# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, android, arrays, csv

I'm making an android app, and I was wondering why I receive a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the my code:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    try {
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("myFile.csv"));
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(inputStreamReader);
        inputStream.next(); // Ignores the first line
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] line = data.split(",");
            entryArray.add(line[1]);
        }
```

The code reads a CSV file and then adds the contents of the second column in the file to a global `ArrayList<String>` (entryArray). The error points specifically to:

```
entryArray.add(line[1]);
```

But I'm not sure why. Also, there is no error when I change this to:

```
entryArray.add(line[0]);
```

My CSV file that I am reading from looks a bit like this:

```
Name,Type,Description
programming,noun,the process of writing computer programs
```

Comment: This fails, `entryArray.add(line[1]);`, this works, `entryArray.add(line[0]);`, therefore, `line` contains only one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answers, but I found the solution:

In my code, I added a log message to test the number of elements in each line array like so:

```
Log.d("This line length", "" + line.length);
```

And I found that the first line only contained 1 element, instead of the 3 that I had expected.
I found that the issue was the line of code below the 'while' statement:

```
inputStream.next(); // Ignores the first line
```

But this was skipping/ignoring elements, not a whole line, so I had to change it to:

```
inputStream.nextLine(); // Ignores the first line
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are reading a blank line, or a line that does not contain a , character. In that case the split array contains only one element.

Consider just checking if the split array is big enough, and skip over the line if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the second to last line to something like:

```
if (entryArray.size() > 1)
    entryArray.add(line[1]);
```

or

```
if (entryArray.size() > 1)
    entryArray.add(line[1]);
else
    entryArray.add(line[0]);
```